# Laravel 7: Undefined variable in foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade, undefined-variable

I want to display to select the campus from the campuses table in my budget allocation create.blade.php template but it displays an error.

**create.blade.php**

```
<div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-md-3">Campus</label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <select name="campus_id" class="form-control">
              <option value="">--- Select Campus ---</option>
              @foreach($campuses as $campus)
                {{ var_dump($campus) }}
                <option value="{{ $campus->campus_id }}">{{ $campus->campus_name }}</option>
              @endforeach
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the text of the error which shows which variable is undefined.

Comment: Which error message you get?

Comment: ```Undefined variable: campuses (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\comon2\resources\views\admin\budgetallocation\create.blade.php) ```

Comment: Show us the controller method what return the view.

Comment: please put your controller method  code..

Comment: @JannVincentPaulLagmay Don't post your code in the comments... Edit your question and add it there.

Comment: ***@TimLewis***
Here is my Budget Allocation controller for the create function:
`public function create()
    {
        $arr['budget_allocations'] = BudgetAllocation::all();
        $arr['campuses'] = Campus::all();
        $arr['end_users'] = EndUser::all();
        $arr['financial_years'] = FinancialYear::all();
        return view('admin.budgetallocation.create'); 
    }`

Answer (score 0):

in your controller you must send the data to the view using second paramter of the view ...

```
return view('admin.budgetallocation.create',$arr);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input :-) it's already working. I put $arr in my view.